# Finding encrypted files and folders under Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, search, encryption

I have a number of folders on my hard disk drive that have been encrypted using the built-in Windows XP folder encryption.

How can I get a list of all of the locations that have been encrypted?  Search doesn't seem to have an option for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How can I find all the encrypted files in Windows XP?**

You can use any of the following 3 methods to locate encrypted files:

**1.** Use the [CIPHER](http://windowsitpro.com/articles/index.cfm?articleid=73838) command.

**2.** Change the color that Windows Explorer uses to display the files:

Double-click **My Computer** and use **Tools / Folder Options**.

Select the **View** tab.

Check the **Show encrypted or compressed NTFS files in color** box and press **OK**.

**3.** Have Windows Explorer display the Attributes column:

Double-click **My Computer** and press the **View** menu.

Select **Details** and press **Choose Details**.

Check the items that you want to see, including **Attributes**, and press **OK**.

**NOTE:** You can use **Tools / Folder Options / View** to **Apply** to **All Folders**.

[Source](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/76493/jsi-tip-5188-how-can-i-find-all-the-encrypted-files-in-windows-xp.html)

*... or do yourself a big favour and get Total Commander as suggested by Nik. :)*

Comment: If it was something I had to do often, I'd do it, but this is a one-time thing - CIPHER command is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: oh, TC is far more than just a convenient tool to locate encrypted files. :)

Comment: @Molly - What's the difference between Total Commander & Free Commander?

Comment: in relation to this question? Free Commander doesn't have the filter "Encrypted" in "Search", other than that, although a viable alternative for the casual user, Free Commander just isn't as good as TC. feel free to test TC for 30 days and compare them yourself (although the program will not be crippled after the eval period, i encourage user to pay the few quid, it's really worth every penny).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/58878/how-to-list-encrypted-files-in-windows-7/59112#59112), [**Total Commander**](http://www.ghisler.com/) is able to search for encrypted folders:

**Commands** > **Search** > **Genaral** tab

search for: `*.*` and select the drive(s)

open the **Advanced** tab, check **Attributes** and clear all boxes except **Encrypted**

hit **Start Search**

Comment: +1 ... looks better this way :P