# Encrypting File System - can you download a file which can turn this on?

Tags: windows-7, encryption

Thank goodness for these forums. I had **somehow** turned on EFS on one folder somewhere on my disc. I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/58878/how-to-list-encrypted-files-in-windows-7) as to how to discover it and therefore turn it off.

To the best of my knowledge I did not turn on this encryption myself. The folder that had it encrypted was from within a downloaded zip file. Is it possible to download a file that has EFS enabled and for it to then enable EFS on the system where the file is stored?

Answer (score 0):

*"Is it possible to download a file that has EFS enabled and for it to then enable EFS on the system where the file is stored?"*

That sounds similar to the description of how the [CryptoLocker virus/trojan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoLocker) works, but I think it uses it's own encryption scheme.

I'd have to say, yes, it is possible, especially when downloading unknown/questionable files to windows just about anything is possible...