# Is this a ransomware?

Tags: encryption, malware, efs, malware-detection, ransomware

I just got this window on my main computer:

[image: Backup file encryption key]

Apparently, it's from Windows. I checked, and the process EXE file is the original one  (efsui.exe or something like that). However, I don't use EFS (I never heard about it). I never encrypted any of my drives.

Is it possible that my system is infected by a ransomware encrypting my files?

Comment: What action specifically were you doing when you got this, because there is no doubt in my mind, you are currently using an EFS.  The good news is isn't ransomware, if it were ransomware, it would have done everything silently and would NOT use EFS capabilities within Windows.

Comment: I was working on a project on VS2015. Is there a way to list all my disks and find the ones that use EFS?

Comment: You can do that through the Properties window.

Comment: Weird. None of my drives appears to be encrypted.

Comment: Did you google "what is ransomeware"? [Possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: I know what a ransomware is... it's just that I saw that encryption stuff, and it scared me.

Comment: EFS works on a per-file basis, so you’ll have to look a *little* harder if you want to find what’s encrypted.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/58878/how-to-list-encrypted-files-in-windows-7) could be useful, to find the encrypted files.